# Filesystemwatcher doesn't work using PowerShell

Tags: .net, powershell, filesystemwatcher

```
$folder="C:\filewatcher"
$filter="*.*"
$watcher=[System.IO.FileSystemWatcher]::new($folder,$filter)
$watcher.EnableRaisingEvents=$true

Register-ObjectEvent $watcher created -SourceIdentifier test -Action {
$path=$event.sourceeventargs.fullpath
$Name=(Get-ChildItem $path -filter "*.inf").Name
$Name}
```

Hi, I put a `direcory` to `$folder` that is triggered the Event

Why `get-childitem` doesn't work ?

$Name returns Empty

Why can not use Source `$event` as Variable Path ?

Comment: The path you get is the path to the *file* that changed. Using `Get-ChildItem` with a file path *and* a filter won't return anything, unless the file matches that filter. If you want to filter by extension set the FSW's [Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher.filter?view=netframework-4.8) property to `*.inf`, not `*.*`. Use `Split-Path $path -leaf` to get the file name only

Comment: By default, the FSW doesn't monitor subdirectories. You'll have to set the [IncludeSubdirectories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher.includesubdirectories?view=netframework-4.8) property

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Hi,Thanks for comments.But I want to put a directory and  then do `get-childitem` to get *.inf name in that directory. Not monitor *.inf as Source Event

Comment: You'll never find any files then. The directory is created *before* any files are copied.  This means there are probably no files to query when the first event fires. Without `IncludeSubdirectories` no event will be raised for the files either. Creating or modifying a file doesn't modify the directory. You need to set `IncludeSubdirectories` at least

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos  it will return the Path if I modify `write-host "$path"`. Is there any different from it?